# Changing back to defaults in Word after defaults have been changed?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

*the title needs some more work, yeah ... *

I changed my Normal template in word (actually, someone changed it for me). How can I change it back to Normal - the one that comes with Word 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally just delete the normal.dotm (.dotm for 2007, .dot for previous versions) file. Word will just recreate it if it is not present. Recommendation: back it up first just in case.

Look in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates

Comment: c'mon, Idigas, give the man a vote, it's well deserved! :)